# Drawing vector icons

Tags: java, android, vector

Some icons, rather than having all the image files on different screen resolutions, I think it's better to keep the vector files and draw immediately.

I don't have any power to draw a new image file, so I want to try with the preset material icon files.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
   <path
    android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
    android:pathData="M7.53,21.48C4.26,19.94 1.92,16.76 1.56,13L0.06,13c0.51,6.16 5.66,11 11.95,11l0.66,-0.03 -3.81,-3.81 -1.33,1.32zM8.42,14.96c-0.19,0 -0.37,-0.03 -0.52,-0.08 -0.16,-0.06 -0.29,-0.13 -0.4,-0.24 -0.11,-0.1 -0.2,-0.22 -0.26,-0.37 -0.06,-0.14 -0.09,-0.3 -0.09,-0.47h-1.3c0,0.36 0.07,0.68 0.21,0.95 0.14,0.27 0.33,0.5 0.56,0.69 0.24,0.18 0.51,0.32 0.82,0.41 0.3,0.1 0.62,0.15 0.96,0.15 0.37,0 0.72,-0.05 1.03,-0.15 0.32,-0.1 0.6,-0.25 0.83,-0.44s0.42,-0.43 0.55,-0.72 0.2,-0.61 0.2,-0.97c0,-0.19 -0.02,-0.38 -0.07,-0.56 -0.05,-0.18 -0.12,-0.35 -0.23,-0.51 -0.1,-0.16 -0.24,-0.3 -0.4,-0.43 -0.17,-0.13 -0.37,-0.23 -0.61,-0.31 0.2,-0.09 0.37,-0.2 0.52,-0.33 0.15,-0.13 0.27,-0.27 0.37,-0.42 0.1,-0.15 0.17,-0.3 0.22,-0.46s0.07,-0.32 0.07,-0.48c0,-0.36 -0.06,-0.68 -0.18,-0.96s-0.29,-0.51 -0.51,-0.69c-0.2,-0.19 -0.47,-0.33 -0.77,-0.43C9.11,8.05 8.77,8 8.4,8c-0.36,0 -0.69,0.05 -1,0.16 -0.3,0.11 -0.57,0.26 -0.79,0.45 -0.21,0.19 -0.38,0.41 -0.51,0.67 -0.12,0.26 -0.18,0.54 -0.18,0.85h1.3c0,-0.17 0.03,-0.32 0.09,-0.45s0.14,-0.25 0.25,-0.34 0.23,-0.17 0.38,-0.22 0.3,-0.08 0.48,-0.08c0.4,0 0.7,0.1 0.89,0.31 0.19,0.2 0.29,0.49 0.29,0.86 0,0.18 -0.03,0.34 -0.08,0.49s-0.14,0.27 -0.25,0.37c-0.11,0.1 -0.25,0.18 -0.41,0.24 -0.16,0.06 -0.36,0.09 -0.58,0.09h-0.77v1.03h0.77c0.22,0 0.42,0.02 0.6,0.07s0.33,0.13 0.45,0.23c0.12,0.11 0.22,0.24 0.29,0.4s0.1,0.35 0.1,0.57c0,0.41 -0.12,0.72 -0.35,0.93 -0.23,0.23 -0.55,0.33 -0.95,0.33zM16.97,9.04c-0.32,-0.33 -0.7,-0.59 -1.14,-0.77 -0.44,-0.18 -0.93,-0.27 -1.47,-0.27L12,8v8h2.3c0.55,0 1.06,-0.09 1.51,-0.27s0.84,-0.43 1.16,-0.76c0.32,-0.33 0.57,-0.73 0.74,-1.19 0.17,-0.47 0.26,-0.99 0.26,-1.57v-0.4c0,-0.58 -0.09,-1.1 -0.26,-1.57s-0.42,-0.87 -0.74,-1.2zM16.58,12.2c0,0.42 -0.05,0.79 -0.14,1.13 -0.1,0.33 -0.24,0.62 -0.43,0.85 -0.19,0.23 -0.43,0.41 -0.71,0.53 -0.29,0.12 -0.62,0.18 -0.99,0.18h-0.91L13.4,9.12h0.97c0.72,0 1.27,0.23 1.64,0.69 0.38,0.46 0.57,1.12 0.57,1.99v0.4zM12.01,0l-0.66,0.03 3.81,3.81 1.33,-1.33c3.27,1.55 5.61,4.72 5.96,8.48h1.5C23.45,4.84 18.3,0 12.01,0z"/>
</vector>
```

A string valuable will be **android:pathData** and I want to know how to draw a vector file with Java.

I don't think there is a way to create a vector with ImageView, even though searching. So I need some help or some tips.

Comment: you can not add any file into resource at runtime.

Comment: @RahulKumar well, I mean downloading a vector string file from the server and applying to the ImageView file using InputStream. Is this impossible?

Comment: ohh.. try this https://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/